# Grub doesn't work after Arch install on an EFI system, how to fix/reinstall it?

Tags: arch-linux, grub, uefi

I new to Arch Linux. I completed the installation following [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/). I messed up the installation of the bootloader. My PC is now unbootable.

How do I reinstall grub, to make my fresh install finally bootable again?

It is an EFI system. According the Wiki, I installed grub and efibootmgr using Pacman, then `#grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=esp_mount --bootloader-id=grub`. It seems to have failed.

Now the problem is that I can't find `grubx64.efi` in any of the boot folders.

Comment: If the install was ready (which is likely), I think you could start to investigate for an archlinux live iso. If it doesn't exist, probably it can be solved also with an ubuntu iso (I don't know arch linux).  However, bootloader installs don't fail without a reason. On the info you gave in your question, we have no way to know, what could be this reason, and this reason is a danger.

Comment: @peterh installed grub and efibootmgr using Pacman , then #grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=esp_mount --bootloader-id=grub  . According to wiki which seems to have failed

Comment: Ahh, EFI! Then you likely did your install well, and the problem is some unwaited interaction between the EFI and your Arch. I improve and vote up your post, maybe you will get better answers. Write more from the details, if you get a question here in comments, answer them detailed. Good luck!

Comment: @peterh is there any way to troubleshoot the problem?

Comment: @peterh the problem is I'm not finding grubx64.efi in any of the boot folders

Comment: Yes, all existing (and recent) EFIs of the world can be made working with Linux. But it is not such a thing that we drop a quick & wonderful solution for a machine from which we can see only an 4-line problem description. But you will likely get one.

Comment: Insert these into the question!

Comment: Ok, I did it for you. I don't know archlinux, but with these improvements you will have more chance to get an useful answer.

Comment: I have a little EFI experience. Couldn't you copy manually that grubx64.efi into your boot partition?

Comment: @peterh second time installation of Arch-Linux , the last time everything worked out since dual booted with Windows. Thought it would be better to clean install.

Comment: @peterh yeah the probem is i don't seem to find grubx64 in any of the folders

Comment: @peterh well it worked out . I seem to have typed in wrong spelled command.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong folder destination - the command input given for the destination was wrong

Comment: Good. Maybe you should read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @peterh thank you . I'm sorta new to this.